# Assign C++ member function to C function pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, boost

I have a C library with a struct like this:

```
   struct A {
      void process(){
        doProcess();
      };
      void (*doProcess)(void);
   }
```

Now, I have a class like

```
class B
{
  public: 
    B(): a(){
      a.doProcess = print();
    }
  void print(){
    // do anything
  }
  private:
    A a;
}
```

This cannot work since print is a member function and has to be called on an object of B. 
Thus I tried to use the boost::bind function:

```
a.doProcess = boost::bind(&A::print, this)
```

This does not work either.

I also tried to modify the C Library and replace the function pointer definition with a boost::function definition. But then the compiler complains about not finding "" which is included in "boost/function.h".

Is there a (easy/boost) way of assigning a member function to the struct's pointer?

Comment: It's simply not possible. Use e.g. [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (or [Boost function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/function.html)) instead. Or use non-member functions, or `static` member functions.

Comment: By the way, the "C" library structure is *not* part of a C library. C doesn't have member functions like you show `A` having.

Comment: I tried using boost::function in the C code. But then the C compiler complained about not finding "<functional>" includes.

Comment: This is the reason that every good C callback system should include a `void *` context argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply cannot do this. Member functions have an implicit this argument that is a pointer to the object on which the function is being called. A function that does not take a B* as an argument will never manage to run on a specific B instance and a function that does not take this point as its first argument can never have the same signature as a class method. For more details on this problem and an example of a workaround read:

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#memfnptr-vs-fnptr

Pay attention to the note at the bottom of the answer on how static member functions can be used in such manner.

Pure C++ projects can use std::function & std::bind to achieve what you are asking about, but a C library used by a C++ project cannot work with these types.